# How do I solve: 'MongoError: $where is not allowed in this atlas tier'?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How do I solve: 'MongoError: $where is not allowed in this atlas tier' when using MongoDB Atlas?

Here is my code:

```
async function getEventsTakingPlace(){
    const getEventsTakingPlace = await event.find({$where: function() { 
        return ((this.eventTime < new Date()) && (new Date(this.eventTime).getTime()+ 100*60000 > new Date().getTime() ) ) }},
        function(err, events){
        if(err){
            return err;
        }else {
            return events; 
        }
    }); 
    return getEventsTakingPlace 
};
```

when I use my local mongoDB instance it works but once i start ising mongoAtlas I get the error: $where is not allowed in this atlas tier. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While `$where` may not be supported by the Atlas tier you're using, the good news is that you don't need to use it for this query.

Instead, use a query like:

```
let now = new Date();
let min = new Date();
min.setTime(now.getTime() - 100*60000);
const events = await event.find({eventTime: {$gt: min, $lt: now}});
```

In general, you only want to use `$where` as a last resort anyway, as it's not efficient.

Comment: How can fetch data by month using mongoose , I have use where condition but git gives $where not allowed in this atlas tier
My code is like
`var month = req.params.createdAt;`
`Data.find({"$where": `this.createdAt.toJSON().slice(6, 7) == ${month} `,})`
how solve it?

Answer (score 6):

I have just been told that the free tier (M0), M2 and M5 Instances have some limitations and command limitations, including limited metrics for analysis. I therefore have to upgrade to get more features....

Comment: you're right, and i see it is listed here.. dangit.. :/

https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/free-shared-limitations/

where, under "Server side Javascript", it says,

$where and map-reduce are not supported.

Grr...

Comment: Upgrade to what though?