# Mongodb: $filter is not allowed in this atlas tier

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I run a query that return an array of users through an aggregation. In order not to return the document of the user performing the query, I added a $filter on his id. But I receive the following error:

> $filter is not allowed in this atlas tier.

I am connected to a free MongoAtlas cluster. Here is my code.

```js
 User.aggregate([
        { $filter: { _id: { $eq: id } } },
        {
          $match: {
            jobs: { $in: jobs },
           age: { $gte: minAge, $lte: maxAge },
          },
        },
      ]).exec((_, data) => res.json({ data }));
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I solve: 'MongoError: $where is not allowed in this atlas tier'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54200300/how-do-i-solve-mongoerror-where-is-not-allowed-in-this-atlas-tier)

Comment: No, it says $where is not supported by a free atlas cluster. But $filter is not mentioned. It should work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) is not a pipeline stage, it's for filtering an array expression. You can just put what you are trying to filter in the `$match` stage.

```
 User.aggregate([
        {
          $match: {
            _id: id,
            jobs: { $in: jobs },
            age: { $gte: minAge, $lte: maxAge },
          },
        },
      ]).exec((_, data) => res.json({ data }));
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I want to return all document that match the criteria, except the one with the id provided. In your request, you would only return one document that match the id if it matches the conditions below. How would you do it?

Comment: that would be `_id: { $ne: id }` instead of `_id: id`

Comment: Thank you so much! For an unknown reason it was not working with _id, so I used username instead, it's all good now!

Comment: It's possible that your `id` is a string, you might have to convert to `ObjectId` like this `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)`